# Selection sort in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, selection-sort

I have to make a select sort function by passing it an array and using max element to sort it, with the two functions swap and max.

```
func Swap(x *int, y *int) {
    aux := *x
    *x = *y
    *y = aux
}

func Max(array []int) int {
    var pos int
    if len(array) == 0 {
        return -1
    }

    maxValue := array[0]

    for i := 0; i < len(array); i++ {

        if array[i] > maxValue {
            maxValue = array[i]
            pos = i
        }
    }
    return pos
}

func Selection(array []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(array); i++ {
        m := len(array) - 1
        posMax := Max(array)
        Swap(&array[posMax-i], &array[m-i])
    }
}
```

It only orders the last element.

input:     array := int{3,5,4,2,1}
output:    [3,1,4,2,5]

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I assume `vector` is typo of `array`. You have to modify this two lines `posMax := Max(array)` and `Swap(&array[posMax-i], &vector[m-i])`. Guessing this is your school work, I do not offer the direct answer.

Comment: Your Swap is broken. Your named a variable aux but it isn't a new auxiliary variable. Note that in Go you can swap variables like `a, b = b, a` and you do _not_ need an auxiliary (like in C). Please take the Tour of Go once more which explain languages fundamentals in detail.

Answer (score 2):

```
func swap(x *int, y *int) {
*x, *y = *y, *x
}

func Selection(array []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(array); i++ {
        m := len(array) - i
        posMax := Max(array[:m])
        Swap(&array[posMax],&array[m-1])
    }

}
```

I fixed it